# What is the difference between the terms smooth, analytical and continuous?

Tags: continuity, analyticity, smooth-manifolds

I saw the following (“roughly speaking”, like the author says) definition of a Lie group in ‘Group theory in Physics’, by Wu-Ki Tung:

“Roughly speaking, a Lie group is an infinite group whose elements can be parametrized smoothly and analytically.”
After this, I was asking myself if I really already know the difference between these terms.

Because, what I know about
1 - analytic: if we say that a function is analytic at a point it means that its derivative is defined at this point and at the points of its neighborhood;
2 – continuous: a function is continuous at a point if you can write a neighborhood of this point where this function is still defined (and this is why those three conditions we learn in Calculus, including that one with the limit);
3 – smooth: I am not sure, but I think it is related to the differentiability of the function.

I think this may be a silly question, but I would thank you for answering

Comment: Smooth usually means "infinitely differentiable." Analytic usually means "equal to its Taylor series on a neighborhood of every point in its domain." There are smooth real-valued functions that aren't analytic.

Comment: In any case... You're aware you can easily look up these terms on Wikipedia, right? Asking this question here is pointless.

Comment: @symplectomorphic That seems a bit unfair. Evidently Poli was misguided regarding analyticity, whether he/she got that from a poor understanding of what was going on in a calculus course or possibly from a resource on complex analysis.

Comment: @Dustan: (s)he is misguided because (s)he didn't look up the precise definitions. (The first sentence of his/her explanation of continuity isn't even close.) There is nothing more to it than that.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Or maybe they looked up the precise definition, and then tried to turn it into an intuitive definition, but did so incorrectly. Or they had a calculus course and obtained a flimsy understanding of these terms from that. And then when they read the precise epsilon-delta definition of continuity, and it reads greek to them (literally), they might just assume it must line up with what they thought was the definition. Only an individual who takes the time to give some thought to pedagogy instead of mere formalism can help with that problem.

Comment: @Dustan: if that were the case, it should've been in the question. We close homework questions with no work shown. There was no work, no attempt, shown here. That's all I have to say about it.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I'm not sure what you mean should've been in the question. I was just proposing some hypothetical reasons that Poli could have been unknowingly misguided; the fact that they're unknowingly misguided is quite evident enough from the question. And for the record, my hypothetical involving the calculus course did not necessitate that this problem was a homework question, nor even that said calculus course was current.

Comment: @symplectomorphic you seem to be one of those that take Wikipedia as the ultimate authority in information. I never trust anything from wikipedia, be it math or politics. For math, I suggest wolfram mathworld.

Answer (score 18):

A smooth function is a continuous function with a continuous derivative. Some texts use the term smooth for a continuous function that is infinitely many times differentiables (all the $n$-th derivatives are thus continuous, since differentiability implies continuity).

An analytic function is a function that is smooth (in the sense that it is continuous and infinitely times differentiable), **and** the Taylor series around a point converges to the original function in the neighbourhood of that point. The existence of all derivatives doesn't imply that the Taylor series converges. A famous example is the function 
$$f(x)=\exp\left(\frac{-1}{x^2}\right) \text{ if } x \neq 0$$
$$f(0)=0$$
This function is continuous and infinitely many times differentiable in $x=0$. The Taylor series around this point is the constant function $T(x)=0$, so the Taylor series doesn't converge to the function $f(x)$ in the neighnourhood of $0$.

Comment: What is so important about $\exp(-1/x^2)$? Why can't we have $\exp(-1/x^4)$ or $\exp(-1/x)$ or $\exp(-1/|x|)$ and keep the function continuous?

Comment: @Jus12 Well, it can't be $\exp(-1/x)$ because that's not continuous.

Comment: @columbus8myhw I agree. My mistake for that one. What about the other two that *are* continuous.

Comment: @Jus12: it's an example. There are many examples of $C^\infty$ functions that are not analytic.