# What do people mean by a "smooth but not analytic" function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, taylor-expansion

Can you give any examples? How does this relate to the Taylor series? Is it trye that all analytic functions are smooth, but not all smooth functions are analytic?

Comment: Cf. [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function)

Comment: The [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) is a good example.

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked and answered before. Here's the link:
[What is the difference between the terms smooth, analytical and continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874820/what-is-the-difference-between-the-terms-smooth-analytical-and-continuous/874852)

But anyway, smooth functions are infinitely differentiable. That is, all of their higher order derivates exist.

A function is analytic at a point if it has a power series expansion that converges in some disk about this point.

Analytic functions are also smooth functuins, but the converse is not true.

Below is a link to an example of a function that is smooth but not analytic:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function