# Proving that the Power Series representation is unique

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, power-series

I am self-learning Real Analysis from the text *Understanding Analysis*, by Stephen Abbott. I would like to try to prove that the power series representation is unique; no two functions can have the same power series. Do you have clue/hint on how to proceed(without giving away the solution/proof)?

> [Abbott 6.6.7] Find an example of each of the following or explain why no such function >exists.
>
> (b) An infinitely differentiable function $h(x)$ with the same Taylor's series as >$\sin(x)$ but such that $h(x) \neq \sin(x)$ for all $x \neq 0$.

***Proof.***

This request is impossible. We proceed by contradiction. Assume that there exists $\displaystyle h( x)$ having the same Taylor's series as $\displaystyle \sin( x)$, but the power series does NOT converge to $\displaystyle \sin x$ for all $\displaystyle x\neq 0$. \

We have:

\begin{equation*}
h( x) =x-\frac{x^{3}}{3!} +\frac{x^{5}}{5!} -\frac{x^{7}}{7!} +\dotsc 
\end{equation*}

for all $\displaystyle x\in \mathbf{R}$.

Comment: Why does $h(x)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!}$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$ ?

Comment: For the record: "the power series representation is unique" and "no two functions have the sae power series" mean two different things.

Comment: The question states that $h(x)$ has the same Taylor's series representation as $\sin (x)$, so my understanding was, it's defined as the infinite series $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{2j+1} \frac{x^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!}$.

Comment: That would imply that the author has deliberately asked you if Napoleon's white horse was Napoleon's white horse. Which wouldn't be unheard of, but may be it's worth checking the definitions of the terms you're reading.

Comment: The point is that having a particular Taylor series and being the sum of that Taylor series are not the same thing.  The Taylor series might converge to a completely different function.  See e.g. the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874820/what-is-the-difference-between-the-terms-smooth-analytical-and-continuous)

Comment: @RobertIsrael, I am aware of this pathological function. I know that, if a function has a power series representation, then it's coefficients are given by the Taylor's formula $a_n = \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$. By the Lagrange's remainder theorem, we can show that the sequence of partial sums of the Taylor's series $S_N(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{N}a_n x^n$ indeed converges to $f(x)$, as $N \to \infty$. 

However, not every infinitely differentiable function has a power series representation.

Comment: So that's the point of this exercise.  $h(x)$ has a Taylor series about $x=0$, the same Taylor series as $\sin(x)$, but it does not have a Taylor series **representation** about $x=0$: that series does not converge to $h(x)$, but to $\sin(x)$.